# menu android not switching activities

Tags: android, xml

Well this is my code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.news:     
                Intent j = new Intent(MainScreen.this,LatestNewsScreen.class);
                startActivity(j);
                                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

this is my manifest lines I added:

```
<activity android:name=".LatestNewsScreen"
    > </activity>
```

and i the latestNewsScreen I must see an simple textView. I press menu and if I click nothing happens. Why Is that?

this is my menu.xml code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/news"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
         android:title="About us" />
</menu>
```

Any help?

Comment: Is `LatestNewsScreen` referenced correctly in your Manifest? Try using your entire package name. `com.whatever.whatever.LatestNewsScreen`. All the code for your `Menus` is correct.

Comment: i think you have not added items in menu?? so where is your `menu.add()` line?

Comment: @imrankhan: what do you mean? In all the tutorials they use the same code as above..

Comment: @aneal:I have inserted the full path but nothing changed.

Comment: @user1267718: your prob solved or not?

Comment: @imrankhan: not, i press the menu, watch the "item", I click and nothing happened.

Comment: @qwerty_gr: OK just make a toast message on item click then see click happened or not.

Comment: @imrakhan: i do not see the toast message either.

Comment: @qwerty_gr: use this `j.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE); MainScreen.this.startActivity(j);` instead of `startActivity(j);`

Comment: @qwerty_gr: if you are enable to see toast message it means your menu is not working. can you provide me link which tutorial you have followed

Comment: @imrankhan: nothing again..:/ my previous example worked perfectly, I dont know what is going on here.

Comment: @imrankhan: this one.http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-an-option-menu,427.html. this code works for me. If i make the changes above, nothing happens.

Comment: ok it worked. silly mistake though, doesnt even worth mentioning. My app had many screens and I was testing it on different screen than i thought. Sorry for it.

Comment: @qwerty_gr :perfectly working on my end and on item click it's starting new activity `LatestNewsScreen`

Answer (score 0):

When you click menu, you should see the menu items (in this case just the one) appear at the bottom of the screen. When you click that item ***then*** your other activity should start.
Maybe your icon is not the right size, try changing it to  the system one, like

```
 android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
```

and see what happens

Comment: Yes i know that. If i use for example a system.out.println i see theresult, or if i use a toast message.I just cannot start a new activity...